# About swamping amplifier problem

Tags: amplifier

I am somewhat new about all the amplifier problems, so I thought it would be nice if I can get some help.

So here's what I need: I need to get values of R1 and R2, where those have a nice relationship of R1 = 4R2 and works on from 1kHz to 10kHz. I must get more than 100 of small signal voltage gain, but I don't think that R1 and R2 are important at all - because the R_c and R_E does it all.
Does the R1 and R2 give the voltage gain something important or valuable? Why?

In case, V_cc is 10V, R_L = 100kohms, and the circuit biases on the right middle of the Q's load line.
[image]

Comment: **If** all component values were given, could you determine gain, bandwidth and the operating point? If not, learn how to do that first. You will need to know about "small signal analysis". And "swamping amplifier" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: What is a "swamping amplifier"?

Comment: I clicked on this to learn what a "swamping amplifier" is

Comment: Think about what voltages are necessary on the base of your transistor for it to do its thing.  Hopefully that starts you in the right direction.